# PRAW Bot: Trying to return number values for word count, with percentages. In Python

Tags: python, bots, counter, reddit, praw

I am using PRAW library in Python to scan a subreddit for most used words in comments section. I have it output to a pie chart showing percentage values, but want to also get more data on how much each word is used. I have no idea what to add to get this data, and I'm sure it's not difficult.

The source code so far:

```
import praw
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

reddit = praw.Reddit(
        client_id='',
        client_secret='',
        user_agent='',
        password=''                        
)

sub = ''

subreddit = reddit.subreddit(sub)

hot_subreddit = subreddit.hot()
count = 0
max = 10000
print('Success.')
words = []
wordCount = {}
commonWords = {'the','of','to','and','a','in','is','it','you','that','he','was','for','on','are','with','as','be',
                'word','we',"there's",'use',"how's",'each','which',"they're",'time','If','way','many','then','write',
                'these','long','make','thing','see','him','two','has','look','more','day','could','go','come','did',
                'number','sound','no','most','people','my','over','know','water','than','call','first','who','may','down','side','been','now',
                'find','this','I','it','has','but','have','they','','be','an','or','at','do','if','your','not','can','my','their','them','at','about','would','like','there','You',
                'from','get','just','more','so','me','more','out','up','some','will','how','one','what',"don't",'should','could','did','no',
                'know','were','did',"it's",'This','The','all','when','had','see','his','him','who','by','her','she','our','thing','-',
                'now','going','been',"I'm",'than','any','because','We','even','said','only','want','other','into','He','what','i',
                'That','thought','think',"that's",'Is','much',"I'm",'I`m','go','still','just','me','This','into'}

for submission in subreddit.hot(limit=1000):
    submission.comments.replace_more(limit=0)
    for hot_level_comment in submission.comments:
        count += 1
        if(count == max):
            break
        word = ''
        for letter in hot_level_comment.body:
            if(letter == ' '):
                if(word and not word[-1].isalnum()):
                    word = word[:-1]
                if not word in commonWords:
                    words.append(word)
                word = ''
            else:
                word += letter
    if(count == max):
        break

for word in words:
    if word in wordCount:
        wordCount[word] += 1
    else:
        wordCount[word] = 1

sortedList = sorted(wordCount, key = wordCount.get, reverse = True)

keyWords = []
keyCount = []
amount = 0

for entry in sortedList:
    keyWords.append(entry)
    keyCount.append(wordCount[entry])
    amount += 1
    if (amount == 20):
        break

labels = keyWords
sizes = keyCount

for word in words:
    print("Word: " + word)
    print("Count: " + count)
    print("******************")


plt.title('20 Most Popular Words On: r/' + sub)
plt.pie(sizes, labels=labels, autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=False, startangle=90)
plt.axis('equal')

plt.show()
```

Any ideas here?

Answer (score 0):

You can use use [numpy.unique](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) with `return_counts=True`.

```
a = np.array(['a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'a'])
values, counts= np.unique(a, return_counts=True)
# values, counts
# ['a', 'b', 'c'], [2, 2, 1]
```

This way you can see how many times each word is used. If you want, sort the two arrays to get e.g. the top 20 words and the times each one occurs.

Comment: Where would this go exactly, in the source code?

Comment: Use it for your words array